# Dio: How to add multiple interceptors?

Tags: flutter, interceptor, dio

I need to add **multiple** interceptors to my Dio object and I don't know how?

I've already added a interceptor in order to add headers to requests.
This is my current Dio Object :

```
Provider(create: (BuildContext context) =>
Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: ApiEndPoints.baseURL))
..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onRequest: (options, handler) {
    final accessToken = accessTokenChangeNotifier.value;
    if (accessToken != null && accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
      options.headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;
    }
    options.headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader] = "application/json";
    handler.next(options);
  } ,
  onError: (error , handler) async{
    try {
      handler.resolve(error.response!);
    } catch (e) {
      return handler.next(error);
    }
  },
)
)),
```

Now I want to add another logger interceptor named `curl_logger_dio_interceptor`:
According to it's [document](https://github.com/OwnWeb/curl_logger_dio_interceptor) I should add this interceptor like this:

```
_dio = Dio();
_dio.interceptors.add(CurlLoggerDioInterceptor());
```

But I've already added a interceptor to my Dio and this piece of code doesn't work for me.
Probably I should use `_dio.interceptors.addAll` method but I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `add` function to add more interceptors with `..` continuation.

```
Provider(create: (BuildContext context) =>
Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: ApiEndPoints.baseURL))
..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onRequest: (options, handler) {
    final accessToken = accessTokenChangeNotifier.value;
    if (accessToken != null && accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
      options.headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;
    }
    options.headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader] = "application/json";
    handler.next(options);
  } ,
  onError: (error , handler) async{
    try {
      handler.resolve(error.response!);
    } catch (e) {
      return handler.next(error);
    }
  },
)
)..interceptors.add(CurlLoggerDioInterceptor())),
```

Comment: It says " The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'Dio' " for the second add.

Comment: `interceptors` has to be added before `add`. I edited my answer.